# incrontab reports modifying a file that doesn't exists

Tags: inotify

I have created this incrontab entry:

```
/tmp IN_ALL_EVENTS /home/me/changes.sh $@/$# $%
```

and this script (changes.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "file $1  changed(flgs: $2)" >> /home/me/changes.log
```

When I use `tail -f /home/me/changes.log` it repeatedly prints this lines:

```
file /tmp/vteH1QPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteNZQPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteH1QPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteH1QPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteNZQPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteH1QPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteNZQPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteH1QPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteNZQPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteH1QPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteH1QPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteNZQPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteNZQPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteNZQPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteH1QPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
file /tmp/vteH1QPVW  changed(flgs: IN_MODIFY)
```

What these files could be? I can't find them in the `/tmp` directory. I also don't see any `IN_DELETE` flag for these files in the log file.

Answer (score 2):

Your whole system may be creating temporary files and removing them constantly from /tmp. Subscribing to all events in this directory seems like a bit of an odd idea, at least you'd expect stuff like that.